# can I use any secondary private ip in VPC subnet to my linux ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a private subnet inside a VPC. So is there any way by using which I can configure any subnet ip as secondary private ip to my EC2 instance network interface.

To be specific, I dont want AWS to do auto assignment of secondary private IP and even I dont want to configure a specific ip from using  EC2 console->"Manage Private IP Addresses" dialog box, but I directly want to assign one of the ip from subnet and configure it on linux box, so is it possible. 
If possible could you please provide some pointers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in VPC you can specify multiple private IP addresses for your instances. The number of network interfaces and private IP addresses that you can specify for an instance depends on the instance type.

See [Multiple Private IP Addresses](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html) in AWS documentation for more information.

Comment: To be specific, I dont want AWS to do auto assignment of secondary private IP and even I dont want to configure a specific ip from using EC2 console->"Manage Private IP Addresses" dialog box, but I directly want to assign one of the ip from subnet and configure it on linux box, so is it possible. If possible could you please provide some pointers